# Meaning of the notation (L2 norm?)

Tags: notation, normed-spaces

> $$E(\mathbf{w}) = \frac{1}{|\mathcal{S}|} \sum_{x \in \mathcal{S}} \|f(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{w}) - h(\mathbf{x})\|^2$$

I was reading about supervised learning in neural networks when i came across this. Can someone explain what the double vertical bar notation means? Is it the frobenius norm squared or simply the L2 norm? Can someone simplify this equation for me.

Comment: It's simply the L2 norm. (Unless $h(x)$ is a matrix, in which case it's the Frobenius norm. But that seems unlikely.)

Comment: h(x) is a vector. So, raised to 2 means i have to square the L2 norm?

Comment: Yes, that's right, we are squaring the L2 norm of a vector.